# how to refine or blur or smooth just the edges?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edges

Is it possible to refine or blur just the edges in an image with the white background ?
I was thinking to get an edge mask of the image ( i already got it). After that use that mask to apply blur or smoothing function on the original image. So that only the edges will be blurred or refined. But i don't know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: You are on the right track. You should have three images: SOURCE, EDGES(SOURCE) and BLURED(SOURCE). Then you need to blend SOURCE and BLURED(SOURCE) with a per pixel weight based on the edges. Like BLEND(SOURCE,BLURED(SOURCE),EDGES(SOURCE)).

I don't know OpenCV, so no real answer. But maybe this helps. 

There are also better techniques to use the edges as actual factors in you blur convolution filter, but the first method is much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an edge mask of the image, do that:

1. Dilate(edgemask)
2. Copy(source: original, destination: blurred)
3. Smooth(blurred)
4. Copy(source: blurred, destination: original, mask: edgemask)

And your "original" image will be blurred.

Comment: hello, thanks alot for your reply... this is my input image (http://oi43.tinypic.com/dg2z5u.jpg).... and i got this edge mask (http://oi41.tinypic.com/5768i.jpg).... dilate function is returning me a blank white image... :(

Comment: you need to invert the mask, white on black.

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov Hi I need help for one my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795643/image-edge-smoothing-with-opencv

Comment: @user2404353  image link has been broken