# Image edge smoothing with opencv

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c, opencv

I am trying to smooth output image edges using opencv framework, I am trying following steps. Steps took from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17175381/790842

```
int lowThreshold = 10.0;
int ratio = 3;
int kernel_size = 3;

Mat src_gray,detected_edges,dst,blurred;

/// Convert the image to grayscale
cvtColor( result, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

/// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
cv::blur( src_gray, detected_edges, cv::Size(5,5) );

/// Canny detector
cv::Canny( detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );

//Works fine upto here I am getting perfect edge mask    

cv::dilate(detected_edges, blurred, result);

//I get Assertion failed (src.channels() == 1 && func != 0) in countNonZero ERROR while doing dilate

result.copyTo(blurred, blurred);

cv::blur(blurred, blurred, cv::Size(3.0,3.0));

blurred.copyTo(result, detected_edges);

UIImage *image = [UIImageCVMatConverter UIImageFromCVMat:result];
```

I want help whether if I am going in right way, or what am I missing?

Thanks for any suggestion and help.

**Updated:**

I have got an image like below got from **grabcut** algorithm, now I want to apply edge smoothening to the image, as you can see the image is not smooth.
[image]

Comment: @Boyko Perfanov I need help in it. I am trying to follow the steps you stated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17175381/790842

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you want to get something like this?

[image]

If yes, then here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::namedWindow("result");
    Mat img=imread("TestImg.png");
    Mat whole_image=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\lena.jpg");
    whole_image.convertTo(whole_image,CV_32FC3,1.0/255.0);
    cv::resize(whole_image,whole_image,img.size());
    img.convertTo(img,CV_32FC3,1.0/255.0);
    
    Mat bg=Mat(img.size(),CV_32FC3);
    bg=Scalar(1.0,1.0,1.0);

    // Prepare mask
    Mat mask;
    Mat img_gray;
    cv::cvtColor(img,img_gray,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    img_gray.convertTo(mask,CV_32FC1);
    threshold(1.0-mask,mask,0.9,1.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    cv::GaussianBlur(mask,mask,Size(21,21),11.0);
    imshow("result",mask);
    cv::waitKey(0);


        // Reget the image fragment with smoothed mask
    Mat res;

    vector<Mat> ch_img(3);
    vector<Mat> ch_bg(3);
    cv::split(whole_image,ch_img);
    cv::split(bg,ch_bg);
    ch_img[0]=ch_img[0].mul(mask)+ch_bg[0].mul(1.0-mask);
    ch_img[1]=ch_img[1].mul(mask)+ch_bg[1].mul(1.0-mask);
    ch_img[2]=ch_img[2].mul(mask)+ch_bg[2].mul(1.0-mask);
    cv::merge(ch_img,res);
    cv::merge(ch_bg,bg);

    imshow("result",res);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

And I think this link will be interestiong for you too: [Poisson Blending](https://github.com/miskcoo/image-composition)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want output like this, I have updated my question, see if you can help please, thanks.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Hope you'll catch the idea.

Comment: WHen I try to implement the above logic, I get something like this http://i.imgur.com/ClXXpbQ.png?1, it seems its doing things correctly but output is very different.. Any Idea.?

Comment: It looks like a problem with CV_8UC3/CV_8UC1 and CV_32FC3/CV_32FC1 image types. The range for the first 0-255, range for the second one is 0-1. Try convert images you work with to CV_32FC3/CV_32FC1 type and scale it by factor 1.0/255.0 . I suspect that the values in mask image you used are in 0-255 range instead of 0-1.

Comment: Also I should mention that used images are: TestImage.jpg - is the image you povide above, lena.jpg - is initial image where you got TestImage.jpg from.

Comment: Yes exactly I am doing the same, the testimage in my case is the grabcut result I am getting, and lena is the original image.

Comment: And what about image types and pixel value ranges?

Comment: Image type is `CV_8UC1` not sure about `pixel value ranges`

Comment: You should convert it to CV_32FC1. And scale by factor 1.0/256.0 . All images should have real element type. I've done these conversions in the code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47645/discussion-between-iphonic-and-andrey-smorodov)

Comment: I am unable to get the output image, and can you please help me ?

Comment: Can I see your code? You can send it to my email: andreysmorodovatlistdotru. Replace "at" and "dot" with "@" and ".".

Comment: @iphonic Did you get something for edge smoothing?

Comment: How do you save the result as a .bmp file ? I tried it but I get a very dark image.

Comment: Just multiply it by 255.In float format it is in 0-1 range.

Comment: can i get java solution of this answer?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov"Poisson Blending" link has been broken.

Comment: @iphonic can you convert that code in java,it will be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  Link retargeted. Anyway you can find larger amount of papers and implementations on "poisson blending" or "compositing" keywords.

Answer (score 3):

I have followed the following steps to smooth the edges of the Foreground I got from GrabCut.

1. Create a binary image from the mask I got from GrabCut.
2. Find the contour of the binary image.
3. Create an Edge Mask by drawing the contour points. It gives the boundary edges of the Foreground image I got from GrabCut.
4. Then follow the steps define in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17175381/790842