# OpenCV : Removing sharp lines

Tags: opencv

Before saying anything I will share my test image :

[image]

As you can see the forehead having a half-circle, and between the circle and the rest of the face in the boundary there is a sharp transition which is quite visible.

If I want to make it smooth, then how should I do it.

I have tried with median blurring inpainting etc. But none giving good results.

Following are some of the result that I got :

[image]

[image]

So what else can be used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use blending, simplest way is to use cross-fade like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795643/image-edge-smoothing-with-opencv/21801424#21801424),  but instead of white image use your face image.

You also can use pyramid blending like in in [opencv sample](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html), or Poisson blending there are also many examples of implementation in network.

Comment: I tried with Seamless Cloning, which used Poison image editing internally.
It doesn't give good result. Almost same as the input image.

Comment: Ok, try cross-fade mask then with large blur, like in first link.