# Anti-aliasing without gradient?

Tags: python, opencv, gradient, antialiasing

I have an image whose edge looks super edgy and blocky. I want to anti-aliasing, but as far as I know, with super sampling, I am taking the average color of nearby pixel to make the image looks less jagged and gradient. But I don't really want that. I need the output to be curvy, but without the gradient effect.

I tried to use `filter=Image.ANTIALIAS`, which obviously does not help to get what I want.

My input Image:

[image: My input image]

---

My output desire:

[image: What I want]

Does this sound like vectorization, and is this even possible?

Thank you

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795643/image-edge-smoothing-with-opencv

Comment: Hmmm, I might be missing something but the top answer seems to gives a gradient edge, which is exactly what I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

This answer explains how to smooth a blocky image. The first step is to get the contours for the image. Then, each contour is converted to a list. That list is interpolated so that no two successive points are too far apart. Finally this list of points is smoothed using `scipy.signal.savgol_filter()`. Results:

[image: smoothed]

Change the `window_length` parameter for more smoothing effect:

[image: changing smoothing parameter]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import signal
import math

colors = (0,255,0), (255,0,255)
max_dist_between_points = .25

# Get contours
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/jaggy.png')
gray = 255-cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 123, 123)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

def distance(a,b): return math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)
def max_dist(points):
    max_dist = 0
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        dist = distance(points[i], points[i+1])
        if dist > max_dist: max_dist = dist
    return max_dist
def interpolate(points):
    interpolated = [points[0]]
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        a,b = points[i], points[i+1]
        dist = distance(a,b)
        if dist >= max_dist_between_points:
            midpoint = (a[0]+b[0])/2, (a[1]+b[1])/2
            interpolated.append(midpoint)
        interpolated.append(b)
    return interpolated


# Iterate through each contour
for contour in contours:

    # Reformat the contour into two lists of X and Y values
    points, new_points = list(contour), []
    for point in points: new_points.append(tuple(point[0]))
    points = new_points

    # Interpolate the contour points so that they aren't spread out
    while max_dist(points) > 2:
        print(len(points))
        points = interpolate(points)
    X, Y = zip(*points)

    # Define smoothing parameters
    window_length, polyorder = 155, 3
    # Smoooth
    X = signal.savgol_filter(X, window_length, polyorder)
    Y = signal.savgol_filter(Y, window_length, polyorder)
    # Re zip and iterate through the points
    smooth = list(zip(X,Y))
    for point in range(len(smooth)):
        a,b = smooth[point-1], smooth[point]
        a,b = tuple(np.array(a, int)), tuple(np.array(b, int))
        cv2.line(img, a, b, colors[contours.index(contour)], 2)   

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```